# Using php & jquery to post data from textboxes to text (csv) file and verify this by reading back to different textboxes on same webpage

Tags: php, jquery, csv, textbox, loading

Very simply, as a browser style UI, I'm trying to read two parameters (provided by user) in two textboxes, save them in a plain text file (specifically a csv but that's not important) on the server but not stopping there, to ensure that these has saved correctly, and as feedback to the user, I want to read the newly saved parameters back from the file into two other textboxes on the same page.

When the page loads, jquery successfully populates the "currently saved settings" textboxes with the values read in from the server csv file using php. When I enter new values and then click the [submit] button to save these values, the server file gets updated successfully.

And it is the next steps where the problem arises, I can use php to read the newly stored values back in from the server file and "alert" them to check that they are correct but the jquery lines to update the "currently saved settings" will not update. I have to refresh the webpage to get these textboxes to update. I should say that the "alerts" display the correct (newly saved) values so everything up to that point works fine it's just the following two jquery lines that work on page load don't seem to get executed at this point.

Hopefully there's something dead simple I'm missing here.

(The csv file itself is simply two parameters used by a complete separate and unrelated piece of software.)

Help much appreciated.

php file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>System Settings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<?php
    $SystemSettings = explode(",",file_get_contents('Data/Settings.csv'));        
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {                       

        $("#txtStoredParam1").val("<?php echo $SystemSettings[0] ?>");
        $("#txtStoredParam2").val("<?php echo $SystemSettings[1] ?>");

        $("#btnSaveSettings").button();

    });             
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $File = "Data/Settings.csv"; 
    $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
    $Data = $_POST['Param1'] . "," . $_POST['Param2']; 
    fwrite($Handle, $Data);
    fclose($Handle);
    $SystemSettings = explode(",",file_get_contents('Data/Settings.csv'));

?>
    <script>
       // alert("<?php echo $SystemSettings[0] ?>");
       // alert("<?php echo $SystemSettings[1] ?>");
         $("#txtStoredParam1").val("<?php echo $SystemSettings[0] ?>");
         $("#txtStoredParam2").val("<?php echo $SystemSettings[1] ?>");
    </script>
<?php
}
?>


<form id="Form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="SettingsForm" target="iFormResponse">
<h2>Parameter 1:</h2>
<input id="txtParam1" type="text" name="Param1" />
<h2>Parameter 2:</h2>
<input id="txtParam2" type="text" name="Param2" />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><input id="btnSaveSettings" type="submit" value="Save Settings" name="submit" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h3> Currently Saved Settings: </h3>
<p> <label id="lblParam1">Parameter 1: </label><input id="txtStoredParam1" type="text" name="StoredParam1" />
<label id="lblParam2">Parameter 2: </label><input id="txtStoredParam2" type="text" name="StoredParam2" /></p>

</form>

<iframe name="iFormResponse" width="300" height="200" Style="display:none;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first script block used $(document).ready() whereas the second does not. Therefore, the second block runs first and is overridden by the second.

Delete the second block and move the code for the first block to the end of the page so that you have only one script block that is reused in both cases.

But since you are using forms and PHP, why not just set the value of the input?

```
<input id="txtParam2" type="text" name="Param2" value="<?php echo $systemSettings[0];?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you - I agree with your last comment about using PHP to set the value of the input directly - I have updated that and it works fine on page load but what I am really struggling with is getting the values in those textboxes to refresh with the newly saved values read back form the csv when I click the Save Settings button without having to refresh the page. I'm not sure I follow the sequence you described about moving the initial block to the end etc. I see what you're saying about the $(document).ready clause but just can't get my head around the solution.

Comment: Forms cannot do what you are trying to do. You would need "AJAX" - jQuery and $.getJSON for that.